# Determining isomorphism between sequence spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

What's a good way to dis/prove that the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of real convergent sequences and that of all real sequences are (linearly) isomorphic?

The former space is isomorphic to $c_0$. Maybe there is an "elementary" solution using quotient vector spaces, but no higher maths than that...

Answer (score 2):

The least painful way I can think of is to recall that if $X$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space, then $\dim X\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Next, conclude that the space of convergent sequences does in fact form a Banach space (with the $\sup$-norm as a closed subspace of $\ell^\infty$).

Finally, compute the cardinality of all the sets involved and conclude that both spaces have the same dimension.